# How to pass session values from one request to another request consecutively using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

When a first request is made, a session id is created. The same session id is being carried to the second request.

In my third request, a new session ID is created for successful login but when I'm printing the session ID for the third request the response is giving a different session id. Why is this happening? And I want to send the session id that I got in the 3rd response to the 4th?

How to achieve this?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt",
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if (!curl_exec($curl))
{
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo "<h2>Response 1</h2>";
print_r($result);
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);

// #######################################################################################

$fields = array(
    'userName' => 'dadmin',
    'logonButton' => 'Logon',
    'actionStep' => 2,
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_string,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

if (!curl_exec($curl))
{
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo "<h2>Response 2</h2>";
print_r($resp);
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);

// ################################################################################################

$fields = array(
    'userName' => urlencode('dadmin') ,
    'pa55word' => urlencode('dadmin01') ,
    'logonButton' => urlencode('Logon') ,
    'actionStep' => urlencode(3) ,
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_string,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (!curl_exec($curl))
{
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo "<h2>Response 3</h2>";
print_r($response);
echo "<br/>";
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);

// ###########Login Completed##################

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/msg/mango/admin/controller/SubscriberMgmt',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if (!curl_exec($curl))
{
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo "<h2>Response 4</h2>";
print_r($result);
echo "<br/>";
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Please **update** your post with the _latest_ code you used.

Comment: Here https://pastebin.com/YLw6eX1N @hindmost

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the cookie file in each request, not only in the first one or two:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "/tmp/cookies.txt",
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "/tmp/cookies.txt",
```

Also make sure the file is actually writable:

```
$cookieFile = '/tmp/cookies.txt';
if (! is_readable($cookieFile) || ! is_writable($cookieFile)) {
    throw new \Exception(
        'Cookiefile ' . $cookieFile . ' is not writable or readable.'
    );
}
```

Comment: That's fine. Actually, in the 3rd request, I'm getting new sessions for a successful login So it generating new sessions. I need to carry that session for the 4th request. not old sessions. I explain in the image clearly. Please check

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri you have to specify the cookie file in every request! If you want to reset the cookies, you would truncate the file but you still need to tell curl where to store cookies.

Comment: Okay, Dan as per your suggestion. I wrote this line file_put_contents("cookies.txt", ""); before third request. But still, I'm getting the same.

Comment: It's worth noting that `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with _**absolute**_ path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a _**relative**_ path.

Comment: I set *Absolute* Path, But same not working @hindmost

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri Update the code in your post with the current one you tried.

Comment: I replaced "cookies.txt" with "\cookies.txt" everywhere @hindmost

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri See my comment under the question. BTW `"\cookies.txt"` is not _absolute_ path too.

Comment: If it is not correct. Then How sessions are working for my 2nd and 3rd request? @hindmost

Answer (score 1):

1. delete all `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,` it save only one cookie, not rewrite it
2. `$fcookies = __DIR__."/cookies.txt";`  init file name
3. Add in all req `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $fcookies,     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $fcookies,`

---

Parse step 3

```
echo "<h2>Response 3</h2>";
print_r($response);

$new_sid = explode("sessionId=",$response);
$new_sid = explode(";",$new_sid[1]);
$new_sid = $new_sid[0];

file_put_contents($fcookies,"192.168.2.35 FALSE / TRUE 0 sessionId ".$new_sid);

echo "<br/>";
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);

$curl = curl_init();
```

---

Wget way

```
wget --load-cookies cookie.txt --save-cookies cookie.txt -S -O step1.txt --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin
cat cookie.txt
wget --load-cookies cookie.txt --save-cookies cookie.txt -S -O step2.txt --post-data "userName=dadmin&logonButton=Logon&actionStep=2" --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin
cat cookie.txt
wget --load-cookies cookie.txt --save-cookies cookie.txt -S -O step3.txt --post-data "userName=dadmin&pa55word=dadmin01&logonButton=Logon&actionStep=3" --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/login/webLogin
cat cookie.txt
wget --load-cookies cookie.txt --save-cookies cookie.txt -S -O step4.txt --post-data "motdContinue=Continue&actionStep=motdContinue" --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/common/loginMotd/w_motd
cat cookie.txt
wget --load-cookies cookie.txt --save-cookies cookie.txt -S -O step5.txt --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.35/cgi-bin/msg/mango/admin/controller/SubscriberMgmt
cat cookie.txt
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, But the same result I'm getting @FAEWZX

Comment: simple parse `$response` on step 3 and re-init curl. Add to post text output - 3 step.

Comment: I didn't get you @FAEWZX

Comment: As per your suggestion, I modified the code, but I'm getting the same result. Here is my latest code as per your suggestion  https://pastebin.com/YLw6eX1N @FAEWZX

Comment: On step 3 button "Continue", please show html it. Wget way same result ?

Comment: Yes, Its giving new sessionId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188251/discussion-between-siddhartha-esunuri-and-faewzx).

Comment: `delete all CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE, it save only one cookie, not rewrite it` - CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION does not save anything, it *deletes* all cookies. (but you're right about that he should get rid the option)

Comment: it should actually be `$fcookies = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."cookies.txt";` - the current code is only valid for linux/bsd/macos systems, its invalid for windows-systems. but with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, it's valid for all systems

Answer (score 1):

because you repeatedly tell curl to throw away all existing session cookies, 
here is the php documentation on `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` :

> TRUE to mark this as a new cookie "session". It will force libcurl to ignore all cookies it is about to load that are "session cookies" from the previous session. By default, libcurl always stores and loads all cookies, independent if they are session cookies or not. Session cookies are cookies without expiry date and they are meant to be alive and existing for this "session" only.

- every time you set CURLOPT_COOKIESSION, **you tell curl to throw away all existing session cookies**, and you set that for every call. you don't actually need to set it at all, unless you want to clear the old pre-exiting cookies in the cookie jar. just get rid of ALL references to CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION - if your old cookies have expired, the server will just give you a new session in curl_exec().

btw you do this wrong:

```
$fields = array(
    'userName' => urlencode('dadmin') ,
    'pa55word' => urlencode('dadmin01') ,
    'logonButton' => urlencode('Logon') ,
    'actionStep' => urlencode(3) ,
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

here the username/password/etc will be double-urlencoded. the code should read:

```
$fields = http_build_query(array(
    'userName' => 'dadmin',
    'pa55word' => 'dadmin01',
    'logonButton' => 'Logon',
    'actionStep' => 3,
));
```

because http_build_query DOES url-encoding, http_build_query is practically implemented like this:

```
function http_build_query(array $data):string{
    $ret='';
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        $ret.=urlencode($key)."=".urlencode($data)."&";
    }
    $ret=substr($ret,0,-1);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri then the website is probably renaming the cookie for you. enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and log the stderr output to find out.